# How to get Directory while running unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, directory

Hi when running my unit test I'm wanting to get the directory my project is running in to retrieve a file.

Say I have a Test project named MyProject. Test I run:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
```

and I receive `"C:\\Source\\MyProject.Test\\bin\\Debug"`.

This is close to what I'm after. I don't want the `bin\\Debug` part.

Anyone know how instead I could get `"C:\\Source\\MyProject.Test\\"`?

Comment: So if we understood you correctly, you have a file in your project and you want to retrieve the file while you are running the Application / Unit Test ?

Comment: Also - you're better off getting the location this way `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Comment: Yes I want to retrieve the file while running the unit test

Comment: For whoever wants a fixed path at starting point. [My answer in Nunit3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59318176/4123703) has a solution for it.

Comment: @abhilash In my case, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location did not return the correct result (when running inside a unit test execution [latest MSTest]).

Comment: @ryanwebjackson - I'm guessing the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` would return the Test Runner you are using to run the Unit Test. Usually, the Test assembly is an input to the Test Runner, so the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` would return the Test Runner's location.

Comment: `TestContext` seems **not** to be deprecated as I read on the
[breaking changes](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/breaking-changes.html) page of nlog. They write *The fields available in the TestContext have changed, [...].* Additionally they recommend to use `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory`. It worked well with nunit 3.13. Important is to add `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }` to the test class.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I would do it differently.

I suggest making that file part of the solution/project. Then right-click -> Properties -> Copy To Output = Copy Always.

That file will then be copied to whatever your output directory is (e.g. C:\Source\MyProject.Test\bin\Debug).

Edit: Copy To Output = Copy if Newer is the better option

Comment: And DO NOT forget, that you need also set the "Build action" to NONE.

Comment: The question of how to copy a file to the output folder at build time is different than the one asked.

Comment: @RickO'Shea The original question was an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). The asker clarified what he wanted to do in his comment - "Yes I want to retrieve the file while running the unit test". I merely provided a solution to his actual problem (and not to his attempted solution).

Comment: I have also used this `Copy To Output` technique and it does work when running unit tests individually. However, it doesn't work when running them from the context of an Ordered Test. I get an error like: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\SVN\MyProject\TestResults\myName_MACHINE 2017-04-26 12_44_09\Out\MySpreadsheet.xlsx`  there's clearly a different subdirectory created for holding the test results, and IDK why my executing code would be looking there..

Comment: @IlianPinzon You can't call any solution you disagree with an XY problem. ;) This is a valid question, and deserves a direct answer.

Comment: @Extragorey Look. This was a question from ages ago. I did not or do not disagree with other solutions. I merely provided an alternate solution. Here's the definition of the XY problem: "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."... Feel free to interpret it as you like... The fact that OP accepted my answer seems to suggest that my assessment was correct

Comment: @IlianPinzon Wanting to get the project directory in a unit test IS the problem, though. It would be an XY Problem if they were asking why `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `null`.

Comment: @Extragorey I have to disagree. Look at the OPs last comment... His ultimate problem was: "Yes I want to retrieve the file while running the unit test" He did not need the directory.

Comment: The actual problem here is that @AnonyMouse should have rather updated their question to reflect what they stated in their comment

Comment: llianPinzon is right you cannot use this solution when you have a directory in output folder

Comment: Setting stuff to `Copy To Output = Copy Always` effectively breaks incremental builds. So, use `PreserveNewest` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "making it part", @Ilian . Should we copy the same folder in Tests project?

Answer (score 56):

Usually you retrieve your solution directory (or project directory, depending on your solution structure) like this:

```
string solution_dir = Path.GetDirectoryName( Path.GetDirectoryName(
    TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory ) );
```

This will give you the parent directory of the "TestResults" folder created by testing projects.

Comment: 2016 answer: Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory))

Comment: TestDir is marked deprecated (2016), think about using TestContext.TestRunDirectory.

Comment: What  is `TestContext.TestDir` ?

Comment: you can add
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
to your test class (name are important) the testcontext will be injected in the property before the test will be executed

Comment: This doesn't work with xUnit. Use Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Comment: TestContext is actually deprecated!

Comment: I  m unalbe to intialize TestContext in nunit3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768812/testcontext-property-is-null @LorenzoIsidori what should be used to if TestContext is deprecated ?

Answer (score 37):

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
```

This will give you the directory you need....

as

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
```

gives nothing but

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().
```

Have alook at this link

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will not work for (unit) tests, as that will return some temporary directory created by the unit test framework. So this is not true.

Comment: when I read the answer, is that good english? I am confused a bit. gives nothing but.. bla bla bla

Answer (score 12):

Further to @abhilash's comment.

This works in my EXE's, DLL's **and when tested from a different UnitTest project** in both Debug or Release modes:

```
var dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Replace("bin\\Debug", string.Empty));
```

Comment: This is correct but the simple answer is: Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Comment: Both Debug AND Release modes... Your code defeats the purpose of my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
/// <summary>
/// Testing various directory sources in a Unit Test project
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// I want to mimic the web app's App_Data folder in a Unit Test project:
/// A) Using Copy to Output Directory on each data file
/// D) Without having to set Copy to Output Directory on each data file
/// </remarks>
[TestMethod]
public void UT_PathsExist()
{
    // Gets bin\Release or bin\Debug depending on mode
    string baseA = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir A:{0}", baseA));
    Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(baseA));

    // Gets bin\Release or bin\Debug depending on mode
    string baseB = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir B:{0}", baseB));
    Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(baseB));

    // Returns empty string (or exception if you use .ToString()
    string baseC = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir C:{0}", baseC));
    Assert.IsFalse(System.IO.Directory.Exists(baseC));


    // Move up two levels
    string baseD = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(baseA).Parent.FullName;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir D:{0}", baseD));
    Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(baseD));


    // You need to set the Copy to Output Directory on each data file
    var appPathA = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseA, "App_Data");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir A/App_Data:{0}", appPathA));
    // C:/solution/UnitTestProject/bin/Debug/App_Data
    Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(appPathA));

    // You can work with data files in the project directory's App_Data folder (or any other test data folder) 
    var appPathD = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseD, "App_Data");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dir D/App_Data:{0}", appPathD));
    // C:/solution/UnitTestProject/App_Data
    Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(appPathD));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory));` idea. I adapted it and used `Assert.That(System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory), Is.True);`. Same thing but more readable

Answer (score 6):

I normally do it like that, and then I just add `"..\..\"` to the path to get up to the directory I want.

So what you could do is this:

```
var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + @"..\..\";
```

Comment: Not sure how you add"..\..\" to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase to go up to the directory

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I fixed the formatting and added an example.

Comment: Or you could do something like this: Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "..\\..\\..\\")

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\..\..\Images\test.jpg" for example works for me

Comment: This doesn't work, it would just append "..\..\" to the string. You need to do something like  Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, @"..\..\..\", "project\\fille.json"));

Answer (score 4):

For NUnit this is what I do:

```
// Get the executing directory of the tests 
string dir = NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;

// Infer the project directory from there...2 levels up (depending on project type - for asp.net omit the latter Parent for a single level up)
dir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(dir).Parent.FullName;
```

If required you can from there navigate back down to other directories if required:

```
dir = Path.Combine(dir, "MySubDir");
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked for me. I have to go three levels up because `NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` returns `{pathToSolution}\TestProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2`. Also `AppContext.BaseDirectory` returns the same thing.

Comment: Actually never mind, `AppContext.BaseDirectory` has a trailing backslash which requires going up an extra level compared to the NUnit property.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/742#issuecomment-121964506

For NUnit3 , System.Environment.CurrentDirector is never changed, so it shall be the path of solution.

Eg:

```
string szProjectPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\where\your\project\is";
```

I prefer fixed location rather than GetParent().
One drawback of GetParent is when build is changed from AnyCPU to x86, default path would be changed from bin\Debug to bin\x86\Debug.
Need to get another parent, and it's pain in the neck.

Also, you may still access to you test assemblies at `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` and get output from `TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory`

Edit:
Note: There are many changes in NUnit3. I will suggest reading through the documentation about ["Breaking changes"](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found was to put the file as an embedded resource on the test project and get it from my unit test. With this solution I don´t need to care about file paths.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but this looks to be briefly touched on in the following question.

[Visual Studio Solution Path environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041078/visual-studio-solution-path-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1):

In general you may use this, regardless if running a test or console app or web app:

```
// returns the absolute path of assembly, file://C:/.../MyAssembly.dll
var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;    
// returns the absolute path of assembly, i.e: C:\...\MyAssembly.dll
var location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

If you are running NUnit, then:

```
// return the absolute path of directory, i.e. C:\...\
var testDirectory = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach relies on getting the location of the unit testing assembly and then traversing upwards. In the following snippet the variable `folderProjectLevel` will give you the path to the Unit test project.

```
string pathAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string folderAssembly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAssembly);
if (folderAssembly.EndsWith("\\") == false) {
    folderAssembly = folderAssembly + "\\";
}
string folderProjectLevel = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(folderAssembly + "..\\..\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
using System.IO;

Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, @"..\..\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use StackTrace

```
    internal static class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetSourceDirectoryName(this Type type)
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);

            foreach (var frame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
            {
                if (frame.GetMethod() is { } method && method.DeclaringType == type)
                {
                    return Path.GetDirectoryName(frame.GetFileName());
                }
            }

            throw new Exception($"未找到{type.Name}源文件目录");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to get the location by recursion

```
internal static class PathUtil
{
    internal static string GetRoot()
    {
        var binFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
        var assemblyName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        return Reduce(binFolder, assemblyName!)};
    }

    private static string Reduce(string? path, string lastFolder) => path switch
    {
        not null when path.EndsWith(lastFolder) => path,
        not null when path == string.Empty => ".\\",
        not null => Reduce(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), lastFolder),
        _ => ".\\"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?