# How to save the output(pdf file) in Visual studio unit testing C Sharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing in c#. I have create a C# method that creates a pdf document.

I would like to write an unit to test method is creating pdf or not. Successfully written.

I am looking for a way to save the pdf file in the out folder of Test Results, Can some one suggest what is the way ?

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Test_CreatePDFReport_ByDocumentID()
    {
        //act
        var result = factory.CreatePDFByDocumentID(new BDDocument { document_id = "1" });

        //TODO:I can save the document like below... Didn't figure out class to pull out folder
        result.Save("");

        //assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Pages.Count > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.GetType() == typeof(Document));
    }
```

Comment: please post what have you tried

Comment: @geekzster posted...

Answer (score 0):

The Envrionment.CurrentDirectory will give you the current folder.

Comment: It gives the bin/Debug folder

Comment: This is covered extensively here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204091/how-to-get-directory-while-running-unit-test